# Show nothing when use matplotlib in python 3.x version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to use the following dataset to get online activities by hours (0-23).

Sample dataset is called `activities`. The dataset looks like this:

```
hour activity_counts
00     2
01     30
02     25
03     40
04     10
05     4
06     8
07     10
08     30
09     50
10     100
11     300
12     600
13     340
...
23     780
```

Here is my code:

```
plt.plot(x=activities['hour'], y=activities['activity_counts'],fmt="H")
plt.title("Customer Online Activities by Hour")
plt.xlabel("Hours")
plt.ylabel("Hour Activity")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The plot like this. There is just nothing on the plot.

[image]

So what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `x=` and `y=`. There is no argument for [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) with the name `x` or `y` (so what you pass with that name will they end up in `**kwargs` and likely ignored), so try it without these:

```
plt.plot(activities['hour'], activities['activity_counts'], "H")  # only this line changed
plt.title("Customer Online Activities by Hour")
plt.xlabel("Hours")
plt.ylabel("Hour Activity")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

There is also some typo: `'activity_counts'` should be used instead of `'activities'`

Comment: Yes.When I remove ```x=``` and ```y=```,it worked.Also,I just remove ``` fmt='H' ```.If I don't remove,there is an error for the format issue.

Comment: @Rya Thanks for the feedback. I removed the `fmt` from the answer as well. Note that you can still use `"H"` markers, just pass it to the function without the `fmt=` (same issue there).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas.dataframe.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
ax = activities.plot(x="hour",y="activity_counts",title="Customer Online Activities by Hour", marker="H")
ax.set_xlabel("Hours")
ax.set_ylabel("Hour Activity")
ax.grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also pass in the requested markerstyle using: `marker="H"`

Comment: Oh... that is what the fmt="H" was. Thanks.

Comment: That also works. I just installed ```plt.style.use('ggplot')``` to let plot more looks like ggplot.